# Absolute import fails in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import

So I have a project with this as structure:

```
Folder
   folderA
   folderB
   folderC
   folderD
```

`folderD` has my project start up "location", in that project I add folderA/B/C as my structre/dependencies.
And now I can do `import folderA.someModule`. Now this is great in PyCharm... but if I want to move to VS Code that project no longer works. Because PyCharm  creates those environments at "runtime"...

Would anyone be so kind and let me know how can I do it in VScode? Or what environment variables should I add to my `sys.path` to make it work? I'm lost. adding some paths to `sys.path` helped, but some imports still don't work.

Answer (score 1):

On top of that, Pycharm does weird job for nested folders.

Let's say we have `main.py` as following:

```py
try:
    import Module

    print("Direct import")
except ImportError:
    from os.path import abspath, dirname
    from sys import path

    path.append(dirname(abspath(__file__)) + "/..")
    import Module
    
    print("Relative import")


from os import getcwd

print(f"Current script dir: {__file__}")
print(f"Module dir: {Module.__file__}")
print(f"Working dir: {getcwd()}")
```

And `Module.__init__` contains nothing.

For following structure:

```
Project
├ Source
│  └ main.py
└ Module
   └ __init__.py
```

Executing `main.py` Does import directly.

```
Direct import
Current script dir: Z:/github/PersonalToolkit/Source/main.py
Module dir: Z:\github\PersonalToolkit\Module\__init__.py
Working dir: Z:\github\PersonalToolkit\Source
```

However, for following structure:

```
Project
└ Root
   ├ Source
   │  └ main.py
   └ Module
      └ __init__.py
```

```
Relative import
Current script dir: Z:/github/PersonalToolkit/Root/Source/main.py
Module dir: Z:\github\PersonalToolkit\Root\Source/..\Module\__init__.py
Working dir: Z:\github\PersonalToolkit\Root\Source
```

Yet for both case Pycharm shows same import hints.

[image]

From this we could guess Pycharm is adding *Project Root* to `sys.path` when running and creates this different behavior.

However, we can't expect does behavior on usual running cases - console, mainly - get consistent results.

Instead, when importing module at outer folder, just import like this:

```py
from os.path import abspath, dirname
from sys import path

path.append(dirname(abspath(__file__)) + "/..")
import Module
```

This indeed is *PEP-8* violation and doesn't look clean. Would be best to have `__main__.py` outside, let it import `main.py` and make `main.py` to run codes on import - without `if __name__ == "__main__":` boilerplate.

```
Project
├ __main__.py
├ Source
│  └ main.py
└ Module
   └ __init__.py
```

Comment: I see thank you! So it is a case of adding paths to the environment then. I have "re added" the paths again now and the app seem to run. I wish that pycharm would generate that "automatic environment extension" code somewhere in file so that I can ref it in my main as `import pyCharmEnviFile` so that it would work for other IDE as well. Thank you for explanation! Even tho in my case I would struggle to use 1 __main__.py as I have multiple projects that I would link to link against similar library in folder structure. Say (client, monitor, user) apps linking to "network" library.